# Android studio 3.4.2 to 3.5 upgrade and 3.5 separate installation(without upgrade) getting crashed always on windows 10 on start

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio was getting crashed continuously after upgrade from 3.4.2 to 3.5. So, uninstalled android studio and installed again downloading the exe file from android developer portal. Still its crashing continuously on Start while showing prompt "loading modules". Not able to find the exact cause of issue.

Comment: When does it crash? On opening?

Comment: when it shows prompt loading modules.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and then installing android studio back?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Same issue.

Comment: In user directory at home like `C:\Users\userName` look for `.android` and `.gradle` and `.AndroidStudio3.x` and delete theme.After that run android studio again @Manav

Comment: @sayres Same problem exists.

Comment: Did you try to use of non installable android studio? I mean zip version?I am using always of zip version of android studio, til now, i do not have any problem with that@Manav

Comment: @Manav any solution found, i also have this issue in windows???

Comment: @Lingeshwaran din't find any solution. downgraded to version 3.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please refer to the following answer i got when i faced the same problem. If you have any antivirus program installed on your system then it's blocking your Android Studio please add Android Studio to it's Whitelist and refer the below link for more details.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57669392/8147020

Comment: Problem resolved after following above step. Thank you.