# My Android Studio keeps crashing after updating it from 3.4 to 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio-3.5

I've been facing this issue since today. Yesterday I updated Android Studio from 3.4 to 3.5 and it was working fine but since today it's been crashing on startup. When I start it shows the splash screen and then tries to load the project and suddenly closes or crashes without showing any error message. What should I do? Is there any error log I can refer to understand what is the problem, please help me with this.

Comment: as always - try reinstalling it

Comment: what is the error log or crash report you are getting?

Comment: hello, I tried reinstalling it but that didn't worked the problem still exists and i'm not getting any error log or crash report, i'm asking for the path of error log of android studio if there is any error log which may have been created when it crashes, then please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After updating Android Studio to 3.5, I faced like you. If you are using anti-virus softwares.

> **Try close any anti-virus software or add Android Studio 3.5 to whitelist**

Below was my problem and finally I come to know Android Studio is crashing because of it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I also have trend micro installed on my system and after unloading it, Android Studio worked fine.